# Android Eclipse export Screenshot

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet, google-play

I just created different layouts to fit the tablet dependencies in Google Play Market. Therefore I need to capture some screenshots. When I do rightclick I can select "Export Screenshot" but it always exports me the default layout size not the xlarge size which is selected (in layout overview I selected 10' tablet)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by default layout size?

Comment: There is the default "layout" folder. Then I specify some layouts for xlarge and large, and I want to get a screen of the xlarge layout. So I pick out a 10'' tablet from the liste, do right click and export screenshot

Comment: You mean you have three different layouts, one in layout, another one in layout-large and another one in layout-xlarge?

Comment: Try to change a TextView text value in all your layouts and then pick a device in which the preview shows your text value from the xlarge layout, for example. Then, just export the screen shot.